# Catching only the first event in NDSolve EventLocator

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a system of ODEs that I solve. During the integration process, there's an event that I want to catch, but I want to (a) continue the integration after the event and (b) catch only the first one.

For example, let's say I want to calculate $\pi/2$ by this method:

```
flag = False;
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
 Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> ((! flag) && y'[t] == 0), 
   "EventAction" :> (flag = True; piHalf = t;)}]
```

For some reason this does not work - the events keep being triggered even though the value of `flag` does change.

[image: screenshot]

In the end of the process I get $\pi/2=17.28$ (this might be disastrous if I'll use this value to build airplanes!) How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two misunderstandings here, both are somewhat subtle. First, giving the `"Event"` option as you did doesn't work because it is immediately evaluated, so that `NDSolve` does only see this:

```
flag = False;
And[! flag, y'[t] == 0]

(*
==> Derivative[1][y][t] == 0
*)
```

meaning it never even sees that the event should depend on flag at all. This can be circumvented by using `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`). Unfortunately the result will still not be what you expect. The reason is that `y'[t]==0` will only fire if at any step `y'[t]==0` evaluates to `True`, which will only happen by chance and/or if the step size is small enough. It is much better/more reliable to let `NDSolve` check for changes in sign and the combination of these changes will make your example work as I think you expected:

```
flag = False; piHalf =.;
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
  Method -> {
    "EventLocator",
    "Event" :> And[! flag, y'[t] >= 0], 
    "EventAction" :> (flag = True; piHalf = t;)
    }
  ];
piHalf
```

I just have seen Nassers answer and wanted to add some remarks about it:

1) Nassers `WhenEvent` basically is equivalent to these `"EventLocator"` settings:

```
flag = False; piHalf =.;
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
  Method -> {
    "EventLocator",
    "Event" -> y'[t],
    "EventAction" :> (If[! flag, piHalf = t]; flag = True;)
    }
  ];
piHalf
```

which is somewhat different: the `"EventAction"` is in this case evaluated at every sign change of `y'[t]`, but only the first time `piHalf` is set. The other solution will only evaluate `"EventAction"` once. For the example at hand the net result (value of `piHalf`) is of course the same.

2) `WhenEvent` has the attribute `HoldAll`, which makes it behave more like the `RuleDelayed` case of the `"Event"` setting which solves the evaluation problem. Using a predicate in `WhenEvent` which is just refering to a global variable seems to cause kernel crashes, but there is a very elegant way to achieve that the event will only be triggered once without even bothering with a global variable:

```
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[y'[t] == 0, piHalf = t; "RemoveEvent"]}, y, {t, 0, 20}
  ];
piHalf
```

3) if you decide to go with the `"EventLocator"` method you might also want to have a look at the option `"Direction"` which lets you discriminate between sign changes from below vs. from above.

Comment: @Nasser: this was not meant as critisism of your solution, the original question wasn't very percise about which of the two would be prefered, if any. I just wanted to explain in how the two solutions differ and also to justify that I wrote another answer. In fact your solution made me look closer into how to use `WhenEvent` and caused me to learn about `"RemoveEvent"` myself, so thanks for that :-).

Answer (score 7):

I do not know why `EventAction` is not working as you show. (could be a bug?) but I just want to give a solution using `WhenEvent` (new in V9) which does the same thing you are trying to do which is to assign a value to the variable `piHalf` only once (first time the event happens), but continue the NDSolve action.

```
flag = False;
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == -y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[y'[t] == 0,
    If[Not[flag], flag = True; piHalf = t; Print[flag, " ", " t=", t]]
    ]
   },
  y, {t, 0, 20}
  ]

(* True   t=1.5707963620260097
   Out[4]= {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[]}} *)

piHalf
(*1.5708*)

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 20},
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {{y[t], None}, {t, "capturing event first time"}},
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{piHalf, 0}]}
    ]
```

Here is a screen shot of the whole process

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @Nasser. Unforutnately, though, I don't have V9, so i can't use that solution. I found an ad-hoc workaround that I'll post soon, unless someone else gives a good solution.